# Padding/Margin of absolute positioned children not affecting parent height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent container div with relative positioning. Inside the div I have a textblock and an image. The textblock has an absolute positioning to overlay the image and the image itself has an object-fit: cover.

```
<div class="landing-cms-grid-content">
     <img src="....." />
     <div class="landing-cms-grid-content-wrapper">
          <div class="landing-cms-grid-subtitle">
               Lorem Ipsum
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-buy">
               Shop now
          </a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

When I give my .landing-cms-grid-content-wrapper top and bottom padding, it doesn't adds to the height of the landing-cms-grid-wrapper. Is it possible to include paddings/margins of absolute positioned children in the calculation of the parent containers height?

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer, no. An absolute positioned element is positioned relative to nearest ancestor, in this case it's the element you're attempting to apply padding to and will disregard the box model attributes of its padding. However you could accomplish the same effect by taking the measurement of your padding you wish to apply and instead apply it to the relative spacing of the absolute positioned element. Eg; `padding-top: 1rem` on the relative parent ancestor becomes `top: 1rem` of the absolute positioned child.

Comment: *"to nearest ancestor"* should be _"to the nearest ancestor with Position other than Static"_

Comment: Assumed that was inferred with **relative to nearest ancestor** which OP explicitly stated is defined as `position: relative` but "position other than static" would not be correct either way since what if parent is position `fixed`, `absolute`, or `sticky` know what I mean @RokoC.Buljan?